# .../4.3.3 (8J3)/.../libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found)

Tags: xcode4, symbols

I've seen this warning before, and I don't remember how I fixed it...

`warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.3 (8J3)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).`

Following that path, I find that...
`/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.3 (8J3)/Symbols/Developer/`
...doesn't exist.

`.../Symbols/` only has `/System/` and `/usr/`

Comment: Sorry if the title makes no sense. I couldn't think of anything better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird problem from old (obsolete?) software versions.

The question is now moot, no?

Answer (score 1):

Change your "Deployment Target" in your project preferences. Select the one matches o your device.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, but I had the same error, after restarting my iPad it was gone.

related: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/17730

Comment: Simple fixes are no good. Cleaning (manual and automatic), relaunching/rebooting of everything, and whatever else can be done without (temporary) root permissions. // That aside, I'm not getting yelled at by `NSZombieEnabled` anymore. (Accidentally attempted to release an autoreleased object.) There must be some connection between that and the search for the missing dylib... (Sounds like a bad movie, doesn't it? Hehe.)

Comment: It wasn't `NSZombieEnbled` that did it, the error comes up when there's some random bug or another that I haven't found yet. (You know, the really fun kind that isn't caught by the analyzer.) // So yeah, problem eliminated. (Can't solve it, but it's dead.)

Comment: I think that this is a debug-only issue, because there's a file missing on your computer not on your phone. Although it's "fixed" by restarting your phone - weird?!
Do you have anything like that in the device logs?

Comment: It's an iPad, not an iPhone, and it's still having trouble. Nothing was fixed by restarting anything. The warning is sent when the debugger fails to find the .dylib. // I now have EXC_BAD_ACCESS on flite (via OpenEars, because the quality is MUCH better and it's a hell of a lot faster), regardless of where it's used. (Seems to init okay, but calling `[fliteController say:@"Words" withVoice:@"cmu_us_kal"];` is lethal. No idea why.)